# Is there any standardised way of dealing with Bower bloat?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I've just finished a site build in which we had to supply our files to a 3rd party to integrate with their systems. The build had to be self-contained as there would be multiple parties with various levels of ability deploying them.

The issue that I'm having is that Bower is installing **everything under the sun** when downloading my Javascript libraries and is not always including a `dist/` folder, or minified versions of the libraries so it's often quite difficult to find the correct files to keep while removing the non-essential files for deployment.

The option to leave everything in was originally considered but it bloated the filesize from 4.5mb to over 15mb. This is the option I might have taken if we were deploying to a server directly but the danger of including a whole mess of code including dependencies, readme's, further grunt and bower files etc just seems too great.

If we are going to standardise on these systems, surely the systems themselves should be standardised in some way to stop us having to manually go through the components directory, removing files and testing to make sure nothing breaks.

Is there a build stage that I'm missing? Is there some grunt task that I should be using to minify all of these files into a single js file and how can I be sure that this step won't add bugs to the project or pull the wrong version of the file into my mega-js file?

Comment: bower is supposed to grab the whole project, not just the JS. yes, you need to complete another step before you "distribute" your app. a builder is a good way to go.

Comment: I'm now using bower-copy which works a treat

Answer (score 1):

I cherry-pick required files to another location which I version control. I gitignore the bower_componants, and do this cherry-pick everytime I install a front-end package, with something like

```
gulp bower-cherry-pick --package jquery
```

It internally uses https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files, and automatically includes bower.json and .bower.json when cherry-picking

Here's sample of [bower-cherry-pick](https://github.com/chandru9279/BuildScripts/blob/master/Gulp/Build/bower-cherry-pick.js), and after you've cherry-picked multiple bower packages, there is an important note: We use what we have cherry-picked and checked into git exclusively, while bundling and including in sources. [An example way of doing this is here](https://github.com/chandru9279/BuildScripts/blob/master/Gulp/Build/vendor-js-pipeline.js#L46) where I simply repoint the main-bower-files plugin to the de-bloated(or cherry-picked) location and bundle, minify and include.

Use bower_components only when you install new packages, and want to have the validations, ordering/sequencing & record keeping which bower offers when installing new packages. In all other times use the cherry-picked files. Best of both worlds.